# How to do multithreading in javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading

Basically I want to do 3 things on my canvas.

I want to draw a mouse at the speed of 60 FPS.
I want to draw shapes after a single second (not necessarily after every second but they will be drawn after second units like 2 seconds or 5 seconds)
And I want to show a timer bar like in a web player. This will be continuously increasing mostly after half a second.

Now I am not sure how to do all of these things simultaneously. I have tried using `setinterval` but I am not sure how to combine all of these three. I have checked the web worker as well but that doesn't allow sending objects so I can't use them as well

Any ideas as to how to approach this?

Comment: Check out [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: If a single thread can handle the load, you can use multiple `setInterval` calls (or `requestAnimationFrame` or any of the other timers).

Comment: Javascript is a single threaded environment. You need to learn to harness the power of async callbacks and promises which emulate multithreaded behaviour.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded, hence you will have to handle your jobs with Promises and asyncronous callbacks, that's the best (and most efficient) you can do. Asyncronous callbacks examples and explanation: http://callbackhell.com/ , Promises: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ . NOTE: these are just some of the available references on the web. I personally really like them though, and they cover most of what you need to accomplish your project. (please also note that callbackhell mostly refers to nodejs, where async callbacks are everywhere)

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad for SO. My suggestion is to focus the scope on just one of your 3 requirements, showing the code of how far you've got to show where you get stuck.